# How can I dynamically import from an NPM package referencing source files directly?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have an NPM package that includes the original source for the bundled module (henceforth referred to as the Feature Package), which is made up of typescript and react code. I have another package that depends on the feature package and contains all the webpack configuration, build/dev server scripts, etc.

Because I need fine-grained control over how sources from the FeaturePackage are transpiled/bundled, I don't import the module in the "standard" way (in which the actual files are resolved via the package.json's `main`/`module` fields). I reference files within the package source directly in the dynamic imports:

```
const featurePackage = () => { return import(/*webpackChunkName: "FeaturePackage", webpackMode: "lazy" */ 'feature-package/src/FeatureModule').then(m => m.FeatureModule); };
```

By all accounts, webpack is resolving the sources/imports and running babel against them (I know this because if I don't have typescript/react presets configured, I get build errors pointing at files in the feature package). However, the resulting artifact says the module can't be resolved:

```
const featurePackage = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'feature-package/src/FeatureModule'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }).then(m => m.FeatureModule);
};
```

So, webpack is able to resolve the files within the FeaturePackage at compile time, and I will get build errors for files in the FeaturePackage if webpack isn't configured correctly, but the resulting module never gets bundled. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: If skipping babel is enough, you can add it to the `exclude` of the rule condition. But webpack will still process the source files.  There is a [ignore-plugin](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/). I'm not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: I do want babel to process/transpile the feature package, and I want it to produce an artifact that can be resolved/loaded via dynamic import. It's the latter part that isn't working.